# MySQL consistent nonlocking reads - rows duplication anomaly

Tags: mysql, innodb

Explanation of [Consistent Nonlocking Reads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-consistent-read.html) in MySQL documentation starts with description of some kind of bug or anomaly. It is in the first paragraph:

> This exception causes the following anomaly: If you update some rows in a  table, a SELECT sees the latest version of the updated rows, but it might also see older versions of any rows. If other sessions simultaneously update the same table, the anomaly means that you might see the table in a state that never existed in the database.

I've found more information about it [here](http://grokbase.com/t/mysql/mysql/0859na0v98/pls-help-clarify-dox-innodb-consistent-non-locking-read-behavior). This question is the same as mine. It is answered by Paul DuBois in responses:

> The background for this change is Bug#30184:

followed by the link I can't post due to low reputation.

But I'm unable to reproduce this bug. 
I consider this to be an important point in understanding how MySQL works. Can anyone reproduce this bug or explain this anomaly (give example of it or describe it in details)?

Comment: Question edited for readability

Comment: It is very likely to be a situation that you will never encounter.  Is your question hypothetical?  Or do you have an example in your code?

Comment: Now I can reproduce an anomaly (I had read-committed level set by default). Yes, my question is hypothetical. I'm just trying to figure out what is going on with MySQL at precise level of examination (esp. in transactions, isolation levels and locking). I also found other examples of strange behavior (strange for me, I consider it inconsistent). But in real life, yeah - it is not bothering me. I plan to give wider answer to this question by myself in future.